# Tomcat 9 Startup Order on Centos 7

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

I have five webapps which are starting at localhost:8080.

- l.war
- g.war
- w.war
- e.war
- r.war

All WAR files store in tomcat/webapps folder. I'm trying to change startup order like above because G app depends on L app. As I read **tomcat starts up with alphabetical order and tomcat doesn't provide any sort of order**. Some people **could handle this with $CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml** but They just do this for one application. I didn't see multiple context. So I tried;

1. Created context xmls in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/ with the naming "l.xml, g.xml, w.xml, e.xml, r.xml".
2. Then I added below lines to $CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml

Content;

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Context path="$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/l" docBase="$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/l.war"/>
    <Context path="$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/g" docBase="$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/g.war"/>
    <Context path="$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/w" docBase="$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/w.war"/>
    <Context path="$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/e" docBase="$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/e.war"/>
    <Context path="$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/r" docBase="$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/r.war"/>
```

I used absolute paths instead of $CATALINA_BASE. This caused some kind of recursive startup. How can i change the startup order of applications(without change their names)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat comitter here, not possible. Tomcat does not guarantee any startup order. You will need to modify the default component for this.

Comment: The absence of such a feature is surprising.

Comment: Same applies for library order. This isn't suprsing since it can lead a load of issues of complexity.

Comment: Is there any tomcat listener on java when tomcat fully starts up?

Comment: Yes, https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/LifecycleListener.html along with https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Lifecycle.html.